# 0 index is undefined or just missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have this into my loop:

```
var part=[];
part[index]={
    title: index
};
```

And this code generates this:

```
1: 1
```

But excepts this

```
0: 0
1: 1
```

What the heck?

Zero index is just missing here.

I am working with jQuery `.each` loop, maybe it's jQuery bug? I tried `1.10.2` and `2.1.1` versions.

Comment: Can you post your complete loop?

Comment: What is index? You should post your `each` loop

Comment: thank you guys for responses but the answer above is a right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you initializing `var part=[]` that it will make the array empty . Only the last value will be inside it . So initialize before the `.each` method , not inside in it .

Comment: thank you. I shall go sleep.